# Notify multiple background workers with a property change C#

Tags: c#, .net, events, event-handling, backgroundworker

I have a global variable called:
`string tweet;`

I run several background workers, that does nothing but wait on value change of the `tweet` variable. Then run a function called: `ProcessTweet( object sender, MyCustomEventArgs args )`

My question is what is the best way to handle the property changed event from all those background workers, and later process the results based on the tweet value and another argument passed to the `ProcessTweet` function.

I tried to take a look at `INotifyPropertyChanged` but I am not sure how to handle `OnValueChange` event from each background worker. Will it run the same `ProcessTweet` function once or each background worker will run an instance of that function?

EDIT:

```
private ITweet _LastTweet;
public ITweet LastTweet
{
   get { return this._LastTweet; }
   set
   {
      this._LastTweet = value;     
    }
}
```

Still not sure how to handle property change event the best way ^

And below is the rest of the code

```
    private void bgworker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        MyCustomClass myCustomClass = e.Argument as MyCustomClass;
        //here I want to listen on the LastTweet Value Change event and handle it
    }

    List<BackgroundWorker> listOfBGWorkers = new List<BackgroundWorker>();
    private BackgroundWorker CreateBackgroundWorker()
    {
        BackgroundWorker bgworker = new BackgroundWorker();
        //add the DoWork etc..
        bgworker.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(bgworker_DoWork);

        return bgworker;
    }

    private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            //Create the background workers
            var bgworker = CreateBackgroundWorker();
            listOfBGWorkers.Add(bgworker);
            //get the MYCustomClass value;
            var myCustomClass = SomeFunction();
            bgworker.RunWorkerAsync(myCustomClass);

        }


    }
```

Comment: Can we see some code? It'll help a lot in trying to figure out what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Baldrick I added more code. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Do you want *all* your threads to respond to *any* new tweet that is set?

Comment: Yes, but each thread should get a different variable of MyCustomTask

Comment: This feels like it might be an X-Y problem. What are you trying to achieve? Why do you need multiple threads to be simultaneously processing the same Tweet?

Comment: because each thread will do a different http request related to this tweet. i.e: bgworker1 to google.com bgworker2 to yahoo.com

Comment: I don't think I would do that with BackGround workers.  I would consider parallel tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok - here's a small console app that demonstrates what I *think* you're trying to do.

1. It creates a 'source of tweets' in a thread.
2. You can subscribe to this 'source' and be notified when a new tweet 'arrives'.
3. You create TweetHandlers which have internal queues of tweets to process
4. You subscribe these TweetHandlers to the source
5. When a new tweet arrives, it is added to the queues of *all* the TweetHandlers by the event subscription
6. The TweetHandlers are set to run in their own Tasks. Each TweetHandler has its own delegate for performing a customizable action on a Tweet.

The code is as follows:

```
interface ITweet
{
    object someData { get; }
}

class Tweet : ITweet
{
    public object someData { get; set; }
}

class TweetSource
{
    public event Action<ITweet> NewTweetEvent = delegate { };

    private Task tweetSourceTask;

    public void Start()
    {
        tweetSourceTask = new TaskFactory().StartNew(createTweetsForever);
    }

    private void createTweetsForever()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            var tweet = new Tweet{ someData = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() };
            NewTweetEvent(tweet);
        }
    }
}

class TweetHandler
{
    public TweetHandler(Action<ITweet> handleTweet)
    {
        HandleTweet = handleTweet;
    }

    public void AddTweetToQueue(ITweet tweet)
    {
        queueOfTweets.Add(tweet);
    }

    public void HandleTweets(CancellationToken token)
    {
        ITweet item;
        while (queueOfTweets.TryTake(out item, -1, token))
        {
            HandleTweet(item);
        }
    }

    private BlockingCollection<ITweet> queueOfTweets = new BlockingCollection<ITweet>();
    private Action<ITweet> HandleTweet;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var handler1 = new TweetHandler(TweetHandleMethod1);
        var handler2 = new TweetHandler(TweetHandleMethod2);

        var source = new TweetSource();
        source.NewTweetEvent += handler1.AddTweetToQueue;
        source.NewTweetEvent += handler2.AddTweetToQueue;

        // start up the task threads (2 of them)!
        var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var token = tokenSource.Token;
        var taskFactory = new TaskFactory(token);
        var task1 = taskFactory.StartNew(() => handler1.HandleTweets(token));
        var task2 = taskFactory.StartNew(() => handler2.HandleTweets(token));

        // fire up the source
        source.Start();

        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        tokenSource.Cancel();
    }

    static void TweetHandleMethod1(ITweet tweet)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Did action 1 on tweet {0}", tweet.someData);
    }

    static void TweetHandleMethod2(ITweet tweet)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Did action 2 on tweet {0}", tweet.someData);
    }
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
Did action 2 on tweet 892dd6c1-392c-4dad-8708-ca8c6e180907
Did action 1 on tweet 892dd6c1-392c-4dad-8708-ca8c6e180907
Did action 2 on tweet 8bf97417-5511-4301-86db-3ff561d53f49
Did action 1 on tweet 8bf97417-5511-4301-86db-3ff561d53f49
Did action 2 on tweet 9c902b1f-cfab-4839-8bb0-cc21dfa301d5
```